# How to validate a phone number prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests

How do I validate if a phone number input starts with `(078, 077, 071, 073)`?

For example, how could I check if `0778772108` input by the user starts with one those numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.startswith()` along with `any()`.

For example:

```
valid_numbers = {'078', '077', '071', '073'}

number = input('Please enter phone number: ')

if any(number.startswith(n) for n in valid_numbers):
    print('Number {} is valid :)'.format(number))
else:
    print('Number {} is invalid :('.format(number))
```

Prints:

```
Please enter phone number: 07812
Number 07812 is valid :)
```